# entity_load or EntityFieldQuery to pull entity ids in Drupal

Tags: drupal

Should I be using entity_load or EntityFieldQuery to get entity ids from a custom entity?

I was going to use entity_load to pull all of the entities in question of a particular type, and grab their relevant information (but that seems like it could be inefficient).

Comment: What is your actual issue? Did you check API on api.drupal.org? entity_load()?

Comment: Check [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) and [Add an EntityFieldQuery example](https://drupal.org/node/916776). But @JoshiConsultancy is right. What is the real problem here?

Answer (score 1):

EntityFieldQuery will only return an array of entity IDs. If that is all you need then EntityFieldQuery will be much faster.

If you need to get the field values you should do entity_load. It is slow but it is the Drupal way.

If it is a very large number of nodes you may have timeout issues. To overcome this use Drupals Batch API or you can use the Database API to write a custom query to pull in the exact data you need in one query. This is technically faster but requires more code and can break compatibility.